# Redirect specific routes to page if they don't exist with laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a route that needs to be redirected to another page if the data they're pulling doesn't exist. The route is:

```
Route::get('{link}/{data}', 'LinkController@getLink');
```

Where `{link}` and `{data}` are model bound with:

```
Route::model('link', 'Link');
Route::model('data', 'Data');
```

As is, when the data for this link doesn't exist it 404's, and if it does exist, it's taken to the page as it should. What I would like to do is redirect to another page if the link would otherwise 404. I've found suggestions on how to do this globally, but I only want it to happen on this one route.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what's the problem? You can do redirect in `getLink()` when its 404

Comment: Won't it only get to `getLink` when it's not a 404? And if it does get to `getLink` how do I catch the 404 and redirect?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the route is model bound. Updated question.

Comment: First of all you check if some data exists and correct, right? If it does, you render a template, otherwise you throw 404? Well, then instead of 404 just do a redirect

Comment: I don't check anything, built in laravel magic checks for existence and automagically 404's if the model isn't found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Link Controller

public function getLink($linkId, $dataId)
{
  if ( is_null($link) or is_null($data) ) {
    return Redirect::to('some/path');
  }
}
```

If either of the passed models are null when it hits your controller method, just redirect them. As for your `/{link}` route that you refer to but don't show code for, do something similar in whatever closure/controller you handle that in.

Comment: This works for non model-bound routes, but not model-bound as I'm using (see updated question).

Comment: Ah, I've updated my answer. The closure solution is in the docs.

Comment: Actually, this was close, but not quite what I needed. The redirect itself isn't working, so I attempted to return null and then check if the object was null, then redirect. That worked fine if `data` was null, but not if `link` was null, or both were. Essentially I need to see if the route is going to 404 for any reason and if so catch that and then redirect. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more code. The closure will execute if the model is "not found". So why your redirect would work for one missing model but not the other missing model is beyond me.

Comment: Dumb question: did you set up a 404 closure for both the link and the data model routes?

Comment: I did not. The problem with that is if you go to just `/{link}` and the link is not found, it should 404. It should only redirect when `/{link}/{data}` would otherwise 404.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you have a `Route::get('{link}'/'{data}')` route setup and then also a `Route::model('link')`. Those are two different, independant routes. Visiting a url like `/{link}/{data}` is NOT going to use the model binding route. It will use the `LinkController` route. So you need to determine if the model is found or not in your controller method for that.

Comment: Can you 404 in your link closure and redirect in your data closure?

Comment: @Jakobud I don't think so. The `Route::model('link', 'Link')` just establishes that the keyword `{link}` represents a Link object to be passed to @getLink. `Route::model('link', 'Link')` is just substituting a link id for a Link object (if found)...if that makes sense.

Comment: Essentially what I'm ideally looking for is behavior similar to a `Route::model` closure, but for `Route::{get|post}`, and from what I can find there is no such thing. The reason I'm wanting this is so that if I have a link with ID 1 and a data with ID 2, you can navigate to `/1/2` and get the correct page, but if you try `/2/2` where link with ID 2 doesn't exist, you'd get redirected the same way you'd get redirected if you navigated to `/1/3` where data with ID 3 doesn't exist, but simply navigating to `/2` where link ID 2 doesn't exists 404's normally.

Comment: At this point, I don't know enough about Laravel magic to recommend a perfect answer. In my experience if what you're trying to do isn't very standard, things like bootstrapping, scaffolding, binding, etc. are probably more work than they're worth. I'd get rid of your model binding and just pass the id's to your controller, then get the objects/models there.

Comment: Your previous comment suggests navigating to the url `/{link}`. Do you have a route for this?

Comment: `/{link}` is in the same format as `/{link}/{data}`, but I think @sudopeople is right -- I think I'm just going to have to de-couple the `Route::model` on this one. I'll re-accept your answer as in its current for since it's essentially what I'm going to do. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the model binding - you've left the cookie cutter realm.

```
Route::get('{link}/{data?}', 'LinkController@getLink');
// note I made the data ^ parameter optional
// not sure if you want to use it like this but it's worth pointing out
```

Do all of the model checking in the controller, something like this:

```
public function getLink($linkId, $dataId)
{
  $link = Link::find($linkId);
  $data = Data::find($dataId);

  if(is_null($link)){
    throw new NotFoundHttpException;// 404
  }
  elseif(is_null($data)){
    return Redirect::to('some/view');// redirect
  }
  // You could also check for both not found and handle that case differently as well.
}
```

It's hard to tell from your comments exactly how you'd like to treat missing link and/or data records, but I'm sure you can figure that out logically. The point of this answer is that you don't need to use Laravel's model binding since you can do it yourself: find the record(s) else redirect or 404.

Comment: Not to jack @Jakobud's answer but I couldn't reasonably fit the whole solution in his comments.

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing, but instead of doing an optional param I did a find on both `link` and `data` and if either were null redirected.